# How to pattern match for the infix / operator in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a recursive data structure in Haskell in order to represent an expression tree. I have this data type:

```
data Expr =
    And(Expr, Expr ) |
    Or (Expr, Expr ) |
    (/) Expr Expr
```

And I would like to pattern-match every data constructor in a function:

```
toStringE :: Expr -> String
toStringE e = case e of 
    And(a,b) -> "and(" ++ toStringE a ++ ", " ++ toStringE b ++ ")"
    Or(a,b) -> "or(" ++ toStringE a ++ ", " ++ toStringE b ++ ")"
    (/) expr1 expr2 -> (toStringE expr1) ++ " / " ++ (toStringE expr2)
```

But when I try to compile, I get this error on the last line of the toStringE function:

```
Parse error in pattern: (/)
```

What do you think I am doing wrong?

Comment: A suggestion: `data Expr = And Expr Expr | Or Expr Expr | (:/) Expr Expr`. Or `data Expr = Expr \`And\` Expr | ...`. But please, no tuples. Not Even Once.

Comment: I see your point, thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`(/)` isn't a valid infix data constructor.  All valid infix data constructors start with `:`.  You could name the constructor `(:/)`, for instance.

The reason for this is that pattern matching depends on the ability to determine whether something is a constructor or not lexically. It does that by examining the first character of the identifier. If it's a capital letter or `:`, it is a constructor. If it's not one of those, it's a variable to be bound by the pattern match.